# Не работают Session Cookie вместе с CORS

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, сессия, cors

У меня клиентская часть работает через **Vue.js**, а серверная через **Python (Flask)**, связь между ними происходит с помощью кросс-доменных запросов (библиотека CORS), но в связи с этим появилась проблема, которую который день не могу решить.
Из-за CORS (скорее всего) нет возможности установить Cookie в браузер, чтобы хранить в нем сессию. Искал какие-то решения, нашел, что в CORS есть флаг supports_credentials, сделал и его, теперь в headers передается параметр **Access-Control-Allow-Credentials**: true и **Set-Cookie**: session=...; HttpOnly; Path=/, но тем не менее, это не помогает установить куки.

Comment: Чистый питон? без django или flask? ты чо за существо?

Comment: @ДанилПерелыгин да, Flask, прошу прощения)